# Column Mapping Using Expressions and Dictionary

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, expression-trees, iqueryable, linq-expressions

I'm having trouble coding an expression for `IQueryable` object. I can't figure out the right way to use the expression to map a string to object properties.

this is my query object and mapping dictionary:

```
var query = context.Industries.AsQueryable();
var columnsMap = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Industry, object>>>()
            {
                ["name"] = v => v.Name,
                ["isicCode"] = v => v.IsicCode.Data,
                ["isicCodeTitle"] = v => v.IsicCode.Title,
                ["isActive"] = v => v.IsActive,
            };
```

and I'm using `columnsMap` dictionary for applying `Orderby` to my query in an extentions class:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyOrdering<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IQueryObject queryObj, Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, object>>> columnsMap)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryObj.SortBy) || !columnsMap.ContainsKey(queryObj.SortBy))
        return query;
    if (queryObj.IsSortAsc)
        return query.OrderBy(columnsMap[queryObj.SortBy]);
    else
        return query.OrderByDescending(columnsMap[queryObj.SortBy]);
}
```

it's ok for `OrderBy` but I need to do the same thing  for `ApplyFiltering` but for filter an `IQueryable` object I need a different expression for where method `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFiltering<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IQueryObject queryObj, Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<T, object>>> columnsMap)
{           
    query.Where(columnsMap['name'] == "test Name"); //this is the problem. 
    return query;
}
```

**the question is how can I use my columnsMap in ApplyFiltering method? or should I change my columnsMap for that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple. The only problem is when you have a value type column (an `int` or a `bool` or a `DateTime` for example)... An `Expression<Func<Industry, object>>` will introduce a boxing of the field/property to `object` that we have to remove. This problem is absent for `string`s.

```
// isActive is a bool
Expression<Func<Industry, object>> exp = columnsMap["isActive"];
object value = true; // You can't use "true" (string) here! isActive is a bool

// Other exammple
// Expression<Func<Industry, object>> exp = columnsMap["name"];
// object value = "Foo";

var body = exp.Body;

// Remove the boxing for value types
if (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
{
    body = ((UnaryExpression)body).Operand;
}

var eq = Expression.Equal(body, Expression.Constant(value, body.Type));

var exp2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(eq, exp.Parameters);

return query.Where(exp2);
```

Example using `string value`:

```
Expression<Func<Industry, object>> exp = columnsMap["isActive"];
string value = "true";
// Other exammple
//Expression<Func<Industry, object>> exp = columnsMap["name"];
//string value = "Foo";

var body = exp.Body;

// Remove the boxing for value types
if (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
{
    body = ((UnaryExpression)body).Operand;
}

object value2 = value;

if (value2 != null && body.Type != value2.GetType())
{
    value2 = Convert.ChangeType(value2, body.Type);
}

var eq = Expression.Equal(body, Expression.Constant(value2, body.Type));

var exp2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Industry, bool>>(eq, exp.Parameters);

return query.Where(exp2);
```

Comment: it works for string types. but i cant make it work for bool properties yet like isActive. can you explain that Remove boxing thing... thank you xanatos

Comment: @Alireza The code should work correctly for `bool`... But you must pass the value `true`/`false` as a boolean/boxed boolean, **not** a string. The boxing: compare in debugger these two expressions: `Expression<Func<Industry, object>> exp1 = x => x.IsActive; Expression<Func<Industry, bool>> exp2 = x => x.IsActive;`. You want the second one, you have the first one in your `Dictionary<>`

Comment: you are right. i'm passing string 'true' or '1' , and it makes another question! how can i dynamically convert values? i need to get type of property from columnMap dictionary and convert the value to target type in run-time. anyway you solve my main problem bro. thanks

Comment: @Alireza A big block of `if`? In the end you need to handle `bool`, `int`, `DateTime`, `float`/`double`/`decimal`. Rarely I've seen other types (`short` and `long` are good candidates)

Comment: Technically you can use the `Convert.ChangeType` method. Updated example.